# Moving to a directory one level down

Tags: java, path

Is it possible to move to a directory one  level down in Java?

For example in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\foo\
```

I can use `cd..` to go to:

```
C:\Users\
```

Is it possible to do this in `Java`, because I'm getting a directory using System.getProperty("user.dir"); however that is not the directory I'd want to work at, but rather 1 level down the directory.

I have thought of using the Path class method; `subpath(i,j)`, but if the "user.dir" were to be changed to another directory, then the returned `subpath` would be different.

Comment: I believe `C:\\Users\\foo\\..` is allowed, so you should be able to append that to the path.

Comment: hi, tried Path workingDirPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\.."); println out the Path
appending .. would not get me down one level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The File class can do this natively.

```
File upOne = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getParentFile()
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29

Answer (score 4):

On my system, the ".." is a valid component of a path.
Here is an example.

```
File file;
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
file = new File(userDir);
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
file = new File(userDir+"/..");
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

Output is:

```
C:\ano\80g\workaces\_JAV_1.0.0\CODE_EXAMPLE
C:\ano\80g\workaces\_JAV_1.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers have pointed out, you can do this using `File`. Alternatively, using the Java 7 NIO classes, as you appear to be doing, the following should do the same:

```
Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/..").toRealPath();
```

Note that "/" is a valid directory separator on the Windows file system as well (though I tested this code on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void downDir(int levels) {
    String oldPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String[] splitedPathArray = oldPath.split("/");
    levels = splitedPathArray.length - levels;
    List<String> splitedPathList = Arrays.asList(splitedPathArray);
    splitedPathList = splitedPathList.subList(0, levels);
    String newPath = String.join("/", splitedPathList);
    System.setProperty("user.dir", newPath);
}
```

Should work. For the levels, just specify 1.