# move git repo down a level/directory

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface

Should be a really basic question, but I'm pretty stumped by it for some reason.

I have a project called `generator-meteor-app`, and it's located on my computer at `/desktop/generator-meteor-app`.  I initialized a git repo in the `generator-meteor-app` folder, but when I pushed the files to github it's for some reason it is including my desktop folder.  You can see it on my profile [here](https://github.com/pcooney10/generator-meteor-app/tree/master/Desktop/generator-meteor-app).

How can I move the project down a level?  I see [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677541/moving-down-a-level-in-a-directory) solutions on here, but they are for people using Java / C#.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone your repository from github into a different location (so we don't accidentally mess something up on your actual desktop).

```
cd foo/bar
git clone ssh://... ./new-meteor-app
```

Now let's use `git mv` and `git rm` to fix it.

```
cd new-meteor-app
git mv desktop/generator-media-app/* .
git rm -r desktop
git commit
```

That should do it. Now you can push those changes to github. The safest thing to do might be to clone your repository again at this point and delete the one that included your desktop.

Comment: Thank you @mkasberg. Jumped the gun and tried the other solution first... Deleted everything on my desktop and am not sure how to get it back