# How can I move down by one level in my directory using Java?

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

Is there a way to implement `cd */` using Java?
On the terminal, this command takes me to the first subdirectory.

While looking for a solution, I came across this answer:
[Moving to a directory one level down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677541/moving-to-a-directory-one-level-down)

But this takes me up, by a level, in the hierarchy. It uses a function called `getParentFile()`. Is there a similar function for the child, maybe?

Comment: Remember any directory can have multiple sub-directories -- multiple children.  So you have to specify which sub-directory you want to move to.

Comment: First based on what ??  name ? Last Modified? index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the current working directory of a Java process (that I am aware of), but if you just need to work with `File` objects, you can do something like this:

```
File dir = new File("/some/start/path");

File[] children = dir.listFiles(file -> file.isDirectory());
if (children.length > 0) {
    /* You may need a different sort order to duplicate the behavior
       of the * glob character, but for example purposes... */
    Arrays.sort(children, Comparator.comparing(File::getName));

    /* Take the first one */
    dir = children[0];
}

System.out.println("New directory is: " + dir.getAbsoluteFile());
```

Or if you want to use Streams, something like this would accomplish the same thing:

```
Path base = Paths.get("/some/start/path");

try (Stream<Path> items = Files.list(base)) {
    Path found = items
            .filter(Files::isDirectory)
            .sorted()
            .findFirst()
                .orElse(base);

    System.out.println("New directory is: " + found);
}
```

In the Streams case you should make sure to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), otherwise you will leak open file handles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using the newer `Files.newDirectoryStream` method.  It does basically the same thing as what Sean Bright posted, although it does't sort the files before selecting the first one.

```
public class DirWalk {
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
      List<Path> subDir = StreamSupport.stream( Files.newDirectoryStream( 
              Paths.get( "." ), f -> Files.isDirectory( f ) ).spliterator(), false )
              .limit(1)
              .collect( Collectors.toList() );

      System.out.println( "First sub-directory found: " + subDir );
   }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `cd */` not sort? Or are you not sorting because you've opted to use streams?

Comment: On my system, `cd */` says `-bash: cd: too many arguments` so I'm not sure exactly what's being referred to.  I assume raw directory listings are not in order, even if the command line typically does sort the result. But basically I didn't sort because I'm using streams.

Comment: Just confirmed locally, it does sort. Thanks.